# SQL Server table not being updated by dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For the last couple days I am pulling my hair out because of a problem I have.

In a stored procedure, I want to use the column name as parameter to update a value in the table.

I have the following code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Item_Update_Single]
    @Id nvarchar(15), 
    @ColumnName nvarchar(80),
    @NewValue nvarchar(80)
AS 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = N'UPDATE [Item] SET [' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ']' + '= ' + QUOTENAME(@NewValue) +' WHERE [Id] = ' + @Id

    PRINT @sql
```

The stored procedure is running fine, no errors, but the table is not updated. If I run the `@SQL` string in query window, the data is updated.

I am a sort of newbie but what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Well, I guess you should *execute* your dynamic SQL statement, not *print* it. See [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You went wrong by thinking a "generic" procedure was a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never execute your dynamic statement. Your use of `QUOTENAME` is also wrong. `'[' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ']'` would result in `[[ColumnName]]` and `QUOTENAME(@NewValue)` would refer to a column with the name of what ever value is in `@NewValue`, not a string literal. You should be parametrising the statement and properly injecting the dynamic object:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Item_Update_Single] @Id int, --Guess this is actually an int
                                           @ColumnName sysname, --Corrected data type
                                           @NewValue nvarchar(80) --I assume this is correct

AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'UPDATE dbo.[Item] SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' = @NewValue WHERE [Id] = @ID;'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@NewValue nvarchar(80),@Id int', @NewValue, @ID;

END
```

This, however, seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Solutions like this are almost always a bad idea and often infer a *significant* design flaw.

Comment: Glad you got it working, @W.Terlouw , but do note my closing statement here.